# Сложить две элемента в массиве и выдать результат?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с числами. 
`arr = [1,5,23,54,123,54]`

нужно сложить каждые два числа и вывести результат:
1 + 5 = 6
23 + 54 = 77
и т.д.

Результат нужно вывести в в строку разделенные пробелами:
6 77 и т.д.

Comment: и в чем загвоздка у вас?

Comment: не могу разобраться, нужно написать код

Comment: По циклы что-нибудь слышали? Вам нужно просто пройтись с шагом 2 по массиву

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1,5,23,54,123,54];
if(arr.length % 2) arr.push(0);

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2){
  console.log( arr[i]+arr[i+1] );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!